# Create Account Button is always going to browser logged in gmail account. How can it will always ask google for permission?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-client

### Project Scenario:

In project Landing page, click on **Create New Account** --> Set same account which was configured earlier .

### **Observation:**

Redirected to Landing page rather providing any validation message

If you login using first email **xyz@gmail.com**. So it is logged in. So your browser is synced with this gmail account now.

Now, you are going to **Create New Account** for new email like **abc@gmail.com**. After clicking, it will go to **"Landing Page"** again and showing **xyz@gmail.com**. Because your browser is already synced with first logged in account **xyz@gmail.com**.

### **Working Area:**

You need to logout after adding new account for removing browser sync.

### Code snapshot is given below:

```
private GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow;
HttpServletResponse response;

GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url = authFlow.newAuthorizationUrl();
String redirectURL = url.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).setAccessType("offline").build();
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

### Question#1:

Is there any other way to always ask google permission window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue adding **'setApprovalPrompt("force")'** in url.

```
String redirectURL = url.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
```

I have go through **GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl** class documentation. There I have got an option of setting approval prompt.

> i) null --> By default
>
> ii) auto --> request to auto-approval
>
> iii) force - to force the approval UI to show.

### Related Documentation is given below:

```
  /**
   * Sets the approval prompt behavior ({@code "auto"} to request auto-approval or {@code "force"}
   * to force the approval UI to show) or {@code null} for the default behavior of {@code "auto"}.
   *
   * <p>
   * Overriding is only supported for the purpose of calling the super implementation and changing
   * the return type, but nothing else.
   * </p>
   */
  public GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl setApprovalPrompt(String approvalPrompt) {
    this.approvalPrompt = approvalPrompt;
    return this;
  }
```